# CSS li dropdown on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. Do these suggestions keep the li:hover dropdown working, just adding the onclick feature for touch devices? I don't want desktop users to have to click, the menu should appear on:hover for them.

I have done my research on this subject but can't seem to find a good solution.

My site http://www.eastbournenl.com

Menu's in question are **'League Info'** and **'Results'** in the top navigation bar.

My CSS dropdown menu activates on li:hover (the li item is NOT a link, I changed the cursor so it appears as a hand but clicking will take you nowhere).

However, clearly this doesn't work on touch devices.

Is there a way to maintain the setup I have currently with the li:hover working on non-touch  devices, but adding some javascript to enable functionality for touchscreen devices?

HTML

```
<div id="link_bar">
    <ul>
        <li>League Info
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="team_directory.php">Team Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
                <li><a href="league_rules.html">Rules</a></li>
                <li><a href="public_umpires.php">Umpire Directory</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#link_bar ul ul {
    display: none
}

#link_bar ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block
}

#link_bar ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display:block
}

#link_bar ul ul {
    position: absolute;  
    top: 1em; 
    width: 10em; 
    padding-top: 1em; 
    margin-left: 0;
}

#link_bar ul ul li {float:none ; position: relative ; padding: 1em 1em 1em 0}
#link_bar ul ul li {width:100%}

#link_bar .drop li:hover a {color: #99FF33}
```

Comment: Look at http://jquerymobile.com/ there are a number of touch events available to achieve what you need.

Comment: there's a jquery plugin called hoverintent which is pretty good for things like this

Answer (score 1):

With Modernizr, you can target touch devices, so include it in your code, and then :

**JS part :**

```
if(Modernizr.touch){
  $('.hasDropDown').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.drop').addClass('visible');

  });
}
```

**HTML part :**

```
<div id="link_bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="hasDropDown">League Info
            <ul class="drop">
                <li><a href="team_directory.php">Team Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
                <li><a href="league_rules.html">Rules</a></li>
                <li><a href="public_umpires.php">Umpire Directory</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

That's weird, most of touch devices emulate hover events.

Answer (score 0):

as you know touch device **not supported** hover effects

you can use some plugin for that,like `Modernizer.js`

another solution i see on the Web is:
`div#menu ul li:hover ul` needs to become `div#menu ul li:active ul` for it to respond on touch devices because they don't support hover states.

my specific solution for you is:
[Jquery Smart Menu](http://www.smartmenus.org/)